# Android - Align TextViews like a table row

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a listview that I'm populating with data and I'm trying to get my layout to look like this:

[image: Desired Layout]

Is there a way to create this while using Linear or Relative layouts?  I tried with TableRows and while it works, it leaves a gap between for the column that divides the left from the right and it doesn't look appealing at all.

Not too sure where to get started....any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a layout with your firsts 2 rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Issue Number:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date Received:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6,046"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="09/02/2008"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is not a good answer, because it doesn't take into account where the second column textviews might have multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

I am writing a sample for one line. Please refer that.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/line1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
       android:text="Issue Number"
       android:layout_weight="1.0"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="0px"
       android:gravity="right"/>

    <TextView
       android:text="6046"
       android:layout_weight="1.0"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="0px"
       android:gravity="left"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

You need to write this for all the lines and then enclose it under the parent LinearLayout with orientation vertical.

Comment: This answer is probably the best, the only thing I would add is that you can specify the left textview to have a weight of 1.0 and the right one to have a weight of 3.0. This will achieve the desired result above.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an xml to format each row in a ListView, whereby each row is a simple horizontal LinearLayout with two TextViews.

So something along the same lines as this:

http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/

A more detailed article dealing with ListViews:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this by placing a 2 LinearLayout inside a single parent LinearLayout. Where parent `android:orientation` should be horizontal. For each row you need to use this technique.

I did use this method for my project.